# What are "page controller" and "page view controller"?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to the ios, I want to know what is the deference between "page controller" and "page view controller" and how to use it with UIImage and UIImageView??

Please give any example and link for the same...

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: i too had the same doubt....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you understand what's the difference between Page controller and PageViewController from the other answer. I'm giving you an example to implement PageViewController using scrollView, you can use UiiimageView on top of that scrollView.

Check out this link: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone

Answer (score 3):

Page controller
[image]

for reference [See This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

And PageView controller

[image]

for reference [PageViewcontroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html)